# Docker-compose dependency does not seem to work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to automate the install of a Drupal website in a Docker container.

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal8
       MYSQL_USER: drupal8
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal8
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: drupal8
    restart: always

  drupal:
    image: drupal
    build:
      drupal_init
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
```

And here's my Dockerfile within drupal_init:

```
FROM drupal

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y wget vim git mysql-client

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"


RUN wget -O drush.phar https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/0.4.2/drush.phar && \
    chmod +x drush.phar && \
    mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush

RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/*
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/web
RUN composer -vvv create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project /var/www/html/web --stability dev --no-interaction

RUN drush si -y \
  --db-url=mysql://root:drupal8@mariadb/drupal8 \
  --site-name=drupal8 \
  --site-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
  --account-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
  --account-name=drupal8 \
  --account-pass=drupal8
```

Everything works fine until I get to the `drush` commands to create the DB tables. I run into the error

```
[error]  Failed to create database: ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mariadb' (-2)
```

However - if I comment out the `RUN drush...` part of the Dockerfile, the container does get created successfully (obviously without the table creation). I'm then able to issue `docker exec -it <containerID> bash`, enter into the container and successfully issue the same commands.

```
$ docker exec -it d16e bash
root@d16e4ff4dda6:/var/www/html/web# drush si -y \
>   --db-url=mysql://root:drupal8@mariadb/drupal8 \
>   --site-name=drupal8 \
>   --site-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
>   --account-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
>   --account-name=drupal8 \
>   --account-pass=drupal8

 // You are about to DROP all tables in your 'drupal8' database. Do you want to continue?: yes.                         

 [notice] Starting Drupal installation. This takes a while.
 [success] Installation complete.
```

So why is this happening? It appears that the mariadb service isn't active by the time my drupal service spins up. In my docker-compose file though, I've got the drupal service `depends_on` the mariadb service, so shouldn't mariadb be available to drupal?

I could in theory split this out into two different Docker files and spin them up via a shell script but that would defeat the purpose of using a docker-compose approach. Any clues on what I'm doing wrong with the docker-compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `drupal` container doesn't know anything about `mariadb` container during the build. Only after you run `docker-compose up` the `drupal` and `mariadb` containers will be available for each other on the same network.

What you need to do is to run your `drush` after you start your containers with `docker-compose up`. You can use `bash` to accomplish that. For example, create `start.bash` file and put:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker-compose up -d
# You might need to put some delay here: sleep 5
docker exec -it <your-drupal-container> drush si -y \
   --db-url=mysql://root:drupal8@mariadb/drupal8 \
   --site-name=drupal8 \
   --site-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
   --account-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
   --account-name=drupal8 \
   --account-pass=drupal8
```

**Update:**
The problem you might also face is that it takes some time to boot your database instance. So even if you run the `drush` command right after you run `docker-compose up` it might still fail. To solve that you can use Docker Compose [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck) or simply put explicit wait before you run the `drush` command (see example above).

Comment: Excellent point on the time it takes to boot the instance - I was running into that as well. Adding an explicit wait solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have missunderstood when the commands inside the container run: they run when the image is built, and the image is built before the services are started.

You need to run the command `drush ...` when the container is started. This can be done by putting it inside `RUN` but the default command must also be run (the command from the [drupal](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/blob/91a83c62f177bdaa4bba79f5f32c4f9972081211/8.5/apache/Dockerfile) image, which in fact is the command from the [php-apache](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/c4f059d09d7eefcb73304d198faa7674610ed810/7.2/stretch/apache/Dockerfile) image, which is `CMD ["apache2-foreground"]`). So you need to combine the two commands into one. One way is to create a `boot-script.sh` that contains the two commands (and put it inside the image):

```
#!/bin/sh
drush si -y \ --db-url=mysql://root:drupal8@mariadb/drupal8 \
 --site-name=drupal8 \
 --site-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
 --account-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
 --account-name=drupal8 \
 --account-pass=drupal8

apache2-foreground
```

Then replace the `CMD` in the image:

```
CMD /path/to/script/inside/container/boot-script.sh
```